# Set the font color in prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, prawn

Im using prawn to generate a PDF output in a rails app. How do i change the color of the outputted text?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have you tried [`fill_color`](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Graphics/Color.html#method-i-fill_color)? Code below should work:

```
require "rubygems"
require "prawn" 

Prawn::Document.generate "hello.pdf" do 
  fill_color "0000ff" 
  text_box "Hello World (in blue)", :at => [200,720], :size => 32 
end
```

Comment: ":at is no longer a valid option with text.use draw_text or text_box instead"

Answer (score 6):

if you use any 1.x version (it's only a pre-release as of writing) you can also use:

Gem install:

```
$ gem install prawn --pre
```

Code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "prawn" 

Prawn::Document.generate "hello.pdf" do 
  text "Hello World (in blue)", :color => "0000ff", :size => 32 
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can also set a CMYK color (in this example 100% key black):

```
fill_color(0,0,0,100)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Use the `color` option

```
text "Red color here", color: 'FF0000'
```

And the result:

[image: Red color here]

With the utmost respect, there is no need to use `fill_color` as of 2022 because you have to manually set and then unset the color - IMO it's much better to set the color directly via the prawn DSL (domain specific language).